# Why is this variable flagged as "unused"?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

My C++ compiler issues a warning that the following 'intVar' variable is "unused".

```
void MyClass::MyMethod(bool bFlag)
{
    int intVar = 10;
    if (bFlag)
        intVar = 20;
}
```

Why does the compiler do this when the variable so obviously IS used? Is this something the compiler should be fixed to recognize as in fact "used"?

Comment: Well, it's initialized and then (possibly) assigned once but it's never referenced. Of what use is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Used" in this context means to read the variable. If you repeatedly write to a variable and never read it, it doesn't matter what you wrote to the variable. This is usually a sign that you forgot to do whatever it is you meant to do with it or that the variable can be eliminated. In your example you never read from `intVar`. Change `intVar = 20;` to `(void)intVar;` to "read" the value and discard the result. You will find the warning goes away.

Demonstration : https://godbolt.org/g/L3rFqM

Answer (score 5):

You have code that writes to the variable but you don't have any code that reads from it. The variable is not used in that sense.

The observable behavior of executing the function won't change if you remove the lines that reference the variable. That's a clear indication that the variable is not used.

Comment: The entire function has no observable behavior.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux - And I believe a release build with most compilers would reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

Just because you assign to it doesn't make it "used" - as the function is currently written, an optimizing compiler will just remove the assignment since it has no observable side effects, this makes the variable unused.